# Does the time needed matter in this parametric word problem?

Tags: circles, parametric

Here is the question:

> Find parametric equations for a circle centered at $(5,6)$ with a radius of $4$  and where the particle moves in a clockwise direction starting at $(5,10)$ around the circle in $60$ seconds. Use theta as angle from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $t$ as time in seconds.

I found an equation that matches the rectangular graph, but doesn't use the $60$ seconds. Was the time just thrown in to distract me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the $60$ seconds so a circle is completed at $t=60$.

The parametric form will be:

$$x=5+4\sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{60}\right)$$

$$y=6+4\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{60}\right)$$

Comment: That doesn't work. The ccircle you defined starts at (5,2); NOT (5,10).

Comment: when t=0, y=6+4=10???  cos(0)=1.

Comment: I don't know how you got y=2 at the start.  When t=0, y=6+4cos(0)=10.

Comment: I typed it into my graph calculator wrong, sorry! It was right.